# Use barcode scanner in VB.Net windows application

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, barcode

I have a point of sale windows application in vb.net and it is working fine. But now I want to use a barcode scanner with it. But honestly I have no idea how to integrate it. I have bought a speed-x barcode scanner from the market and connected it to the laptop but its not scanning anything but weird beeps only. (the installation is fine) I thought it would automatically read and punch text into a textbox when a textbox is focused. but its not that simple I guess. any ideas or tutorial for this problem? Please note that I am a beginner level programmer and this is my first application ever. I have researched as much as I could and did not find any proper solution therefore posting my question here.

Comment: What has the hardware documentation told you?  Hoping something is as simple as plug and play is fine but, if it isn't, the next step is to read the instructions.

Comment: Pay special attention to the types of barcode the scanner will recognize, and make sure yours will work.

Comment: Barcode scanner have nothing to do with your application. Your assumptions that it will input text into focused textbox is correct. Scanner is just another input device(keyboard). You need integrate it with operation system. Check hardware documentation for installation

Comment: The manual guide only have few dozen barcode samples on it and product specification i.e. Scanning type: bi-directional, decoding capability: UPC/EAN, code 128, Code39, Code39 full ASCII, Coda bar, Code93, MSI, Code11, ISBN, ISSN

Comment: @Fabio Yeah but the problem is that there is not detailed documentation with the device just a single paper with many barcodes on it and product specification. i opened text editors notepad, wordpad, ms word and scanned the barcodes on that product manual guide but the scanner is making a beep without showing any text into the text editor.

Comment: Google may help for more information. Check maybe scanner needs some driver to be installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aright! So at last i have found the solution and that is the user manual that contained different barcodes are to activate and deactivate features of the barcode scanner (ON/OFF). and there was a barcode with tite "Restore Defaults" and as i scanned that the problem resolved. Now i can scan anything and the result is getting displayed in the textbox accurately.
Posting the answer so that in future if anyone else faces the same problem then this could be of any help. Thanks everyone who took time and provided valuable suggestions to the problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Barcode scanners are just specialized keyboards. When they scan a code, they send keystrokes for the code followed by the carriage return to the OS. Your app doesn't have to do anything special beyond accepting that text.

If you're not seeing the barcode show up in a text editor, something is not connected between the computer and scanner.

Answer (score -1):

Based on my experience I used Bar Code Scanner the one that looks like a gun and I'm happy that it is plug and play means whether i focus it and test an item it results to a good one.

I remember when I have it what I did is just put textbox in a form,run it,scan my junk food and it worked.

Take consider that today's tech everything would be easy.

So what would be my answer for you? Go back to the store where you buy it and replace it with the one that is plug and play and did you test it in the store? maybe it is broken.

Sorry for this kind of answer but it make sense

Comment: I really appreciate your time and answer to my question. it is a plug and play barcode scanner. i connected it through the usb and the green light on the scanner turned on and system prompted that installation is successful.  when i focus a barcode and press the trigger button it focus the barcode and makes a beep with red light which apparently shows its working but i don't know why its not showing text in the text editor.

Comment: Did your cursor is focused on a textfield? Have you restart your PC?

Comment: Posted the Solution bro in my Answer. the problem was just to reset the settings of the barcode scanner by just scanning the restore barcode and the problem is resolved.